# keras model.fit_generator() several times slower than model.fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Even as of Keras 1.2.2, referencing [merge](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2730), it does have multiprocessing included, but `model.fit_generator()` is still about 4-5x slower than `model.fit()` due to disk reading speed limitations. How can this be sped up, say through additional multiprocessing?

Comment: It depends where the bottleneck is... If it's reading speed limitations, increase the batch_size to slow down your training step and increase the queue size and nb of worker. Are you training on GPU or CPU?

Comment: It would be also great if you provide the details about your data, batch size, kind of loading, etc.

Comment: Training is on GPU.  I've changed batch size from 32, 64, to 128, and there are no significant differences in speed.

Comment: It is supposed to be slower by design. There is a lot of I/O related overhead in `fit_generator` that is not present in `fit()`. A SSD may be the way to mitigate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the `workers` and `max_queue_size` parameters of `fit_generator()` in the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/). Essentially, more `workers` creates more threads for loading the data into the queue that feeds data to your network. There is a chance that filling the queue might cause memory problems, though, so you might want to decrease `max_queue_size` to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I switched to dask to load the data into memory rather than using a generator where I was using pandas. So, depending on your data size, if possible, load the data into memory and use the fit function.